# Is this the best way to go about setting up and maintaining session variables in WebMatrix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I have in the past always had quite a few problems maintaining the session state with WebMatrix, and handling them when expecting them to be timed-out (mainly because I am still learning).

The user input must always be remembered, because if they submit and a custom error occurs, I don't want them to have to re-input all of the information back into the form.

I think I have a method figured out (finally) that can properly maintain and manage timed-out session variables in the future, when they are needed.

I realize that there are several other methods of transferring data between web pages, and believe me, when applicable, they will certainly be used first. This question only pertains to when I feel like the session variable is my best option.

My problem is, I always think I have it figured out, and then, only after I have set up over half of the coding, do I realize why it doesn't quite work, and then find some sloppy (but effective) work around that will at least work for that project.

The projects I will use session variables in use the common database with web interface combination. Usually there are 3 main pages: an add entry page, an edit entry page, and a lookup entry page. The add entry page and the lookup entry page eventually post and redirect to the edit entry page.

Before I begin my next project, I thought it would be wise to inquire if my method is at least aiming in the right direction, or if I am still not approaching this quite right.

Here is what I think might work (although, it seems a bit too easy):

1. Use local variables per page.
2. In an (IsPost) branch assign the session variables based off of the local variables just before posting/redirecting.
3. On the other page, just after being redirected, use the session variables to assign new static local variables.

In other words: I will (when necessary) use the session variables only to transfer the data which will happen in a completely acceptable amount of time (not allowing the session state enough time to timeout), and then referring only to the local variables when needed, per page.

Am I crazy or is this the best way (or at least a decently viable way) to handle this, when forced to work with the session state in WebMatrix?

Sorry if this is a stupid question xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should not use Session variables to remember what the user entered into the form. The form - add or edit - should post to itself for validation. That way, the values are available in the Request.Form collection. You can easily repopulate the form in the event of a validation error. On successful submission, you insert or update the database, and then redirect to another page to prevent duplicate submission.

Session variables are really easy to use if used appropriately. I suspect your difficulties arise because you are using them for the wrong scenarios.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I do post back to the same page, during which I validate then insert/update the database accordingly. However, I find the need to remember which entry ID was used so I can query it on the edits page (e.g., when they save a new entry, it immediately goes to the edit entry page for viewing, etc.). I learn more everyday, so maybe my next project will be cleaner, but for now, it is too late to turn back. I must make this work, and I'm sure I will, at least so the user doesn't notice, lol. Just knowing your approach teaches me something. Thanks!

Comment: Is my aforementioned scenario even acceptable, at all? Albeit there is probably a better way (I guess what I don't get is that with redirect, I can't POST so I can't use IsPost or a Request.Form on the other side. In a lot of cases, I'm sure query strings would work just fine, but I have, multiple times, not wanted to display the data due to information sensitivity issues. I don't suppose there is a way to redirect and keep the Request.Form collection without using session variables is there? ..... I didn't think so. :)

Comment: Sorry, just read my above comment, and I just want to say that my "I didn't think so" at the end was meant to be comical negativity, not rude. Sorry if it came across that way. Just wanted to clarify that, sometimes I "post" my foot in my mouth xD

Comment: I have never known a situation where the ID of the newly created record is _more_ sensitive than the actual data that the user just entered. But if you cannot rely on session data persisting more than one request, you could look at encrypting the data and putting that in your query string.

Comment: Sounds like good advice, however, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.google.com/search?q=asp+net+encrypt+querystring

Comment: Right, you are. Again, man, I can't thank you enough for all of your help over the past months (not just this post), as you have a knack for educating those who are beginners with asp.net and WebMatrix, in general.

Comment: I only have one more question: Right after I perform the db.execute to insert a new entry into the database, if the ID Is Identity and automatically increments, would using MAX (aggregate function in sql), just after inserting, on said ID field, always return the entry I just inserted, provided that there could be a slew of users out there potentially inserting new entries at the same time? Is there a better way to ensure I select the same entry just added by that user?

Comment: Right after you have performed yor db.Execute to create the new record, you should call `var newId = db.GetLastInsertId()` to get the ID of that record: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.getlastinsertid(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Ahhhh! What would I do without you, Sir? Thanks, Mike!

Comment: I'm assuming that db is still the variable which I have assigned my Database.Open("DatabaseName") statement, but I've noticed that just using this db.GetLastInsertId() never tells the database the table name. Does it just look for the latest id in any table? Also, does this still work when the primary key for the database is 'not' identity? I looked at the link you posted for that method, but it doesn't really offer much information or examples on its use.

Comment: Yes - you use the existing Database variable, and it will retrieve the identity value for the most recently created row on this connection where the primary key is an Identity type.

Comment: That's about as concise an answer (answers really) as anyone could hope for. I have no further questions, Your Honor... :) Thanks again, really!